# create the new user in xmpp account programmatically in android

Tags: android, xmpp

public class RegisterConnection extends Activity 
{

```
public static final String HOST = "ip";
public static final int PORT = 5222;
public static final String SERVICE = "ip";

private String username;
private String name;
private String email_id;
private String password;
private String cmpassword;
private String user;
private String nam;
private String emailid;
private String pass;
private String cmpass;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getIntentData();
    connect();

}

private void getIntentData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Intent getData=getIntent();
    username=getData.getStringExtra("username");
    name=getData.getStringExtra("name");
    email_id=getData.getStringExtra("email_id");
    password=getData.getStringExtra("password");
    cmpassword=getData.getStringExtra("cmpassword");

}

private void connect() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Connecting...", "Please wait...", false);

    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(
                    HOST, PORT,SERVICE);
            XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);

            try {
                connection.connect();
                Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                        "Connected to " + connection.getHost());
            } catch (XMPPException ex) 
            {
                Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Failed to connect to "
                        + connection.getHost());
                Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", ex.toString());
            //  setConnection(null);
            }

            try{

                //connection.connect();

                Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity","Logged in as " + connection.getUser());
                String kk= connection.getUser();
                AccountManager accountManager = connection.getAccountManager();
                Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<String, String>();
                attributes.put("Username", username);
                attributes.put("Name", name);
                attributes.put("Email", email_id);
                attributes.put("Password", password);
                attributes.put("Confirm Password", cmpassword);

                accountManager.createAccount("ip","",attributes);

                Registration registration = new Registration();
                registration.setType(IQ.Type.SET);
                registration.setTo(connection.getServiceName());

                PacketFilter filter = new AndFilter(new PacketIDFilter(registration.getPacketID()), new PacketTypeFilter(IQ.class));
                PacketCollector collector = connection.createPacketCollector(filter);
        connection.sendPacket(registration);
        connection.disconnect();
//      connection.connect();
               // connection.login(username, password);
                Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity","Logged in as " + connection.getUser());


               /* AccountManager accountManager = connection.getAccountManager();
                Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<String, String>();
                attributes.put("username", "krishna");
                attributes.put("password", "123456");
                attributes.put("email", "krishna@gmail.com");
                attributes.put("name", "krishnathakkar");

                accountManager.createAccount("krishna@target.local", "123456",attributes);

                Registration registration = new Registration();
                registration.setType(IQ.Type.SET);
                registration.setTo(connection.getServiceName());

                PacketFilter filter = new AndFilter(new PacketIDFilter(registration.getPacketID()), new PacketTypeFilter(IQ.class));
                PacketCollector collector = connection.createPacketCollector(filter);
                connection.sendPacket(registration);

                connection.connect();*/

            }catch(XMPPException ex){

                Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Failed to Register in as "
                        + username);
                 connection.disconnect();

            }


        }

});
    t.start();
    dialog.show();

}
}
```

> Blockquote

i have tried the above code for registration but it giving me error
and saying no Response form server 
and registration failed.
the connection is been done successfully with the server.
but not allowing me to create the new user

Comment: post error.so i can help

Comment: Connected to 45.56.87.223

Comment: com.demo.xmppchat.RegisterConnection$1.run(RegisterConnection.java:93)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

Comment: and retruning no reponse form the server

Comment: remove the ip address from you this code.Anybody can login to your openfire console using this ip.so remove it for your safety

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all remove these lines you don't need to login to create an account.

```
            connection.login("admin", "admin");
            Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity","Logged in as " + connection.getUser());
            String kk= connection.getUser();
```

And also keep either below code

```
            Registration registration = new Registration();
            registration.setType(IQ.Type.SET);
            registration.setTo(connection.getServiceName());

            PacketFilter filter = new AndFilter(new PacketIDFilter(registration.getPacketID()), new PacketTypeFilter(IQ.class));
            PacketCollector collector =   connection.createPacketCollector(filter);
            connection.sendPacket(registration);
            connection.disconnect();
```

Or this

```
            AccountManager accountManager = connection.getAccountManager();
            Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<String, String>();
            attributes.put("Username", username);
            attributes.put("Name", name);
            attributes.put("Email", email_id);
            attributes.put("Password", password);
            attributes.put("Confirm Password", cmpassword);

            accountManager.createAccount("45.56.87.223","5222",attributes);
```

As both codes can be used for registartion.You don't need both of these codes to register a user.Use any one of them.And you are done.

And also check from the openfire settings that nband Account Registration is enabled.Hope it will help.Thanks.